# Proper Use of JSON

Tags: python, sql, objective-c, json, format

Is it proper to parse through multiple HTML files in Python (Beautiful Soup), and then store the information in JSON format which will be iterated in Objective-C?  If not, how should I format it? (I.e. XML, SQL, etc.?)

Thanks!

Edit: The situation I am dealing is the same as my previous question (although a different aspect is being discussed).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836836/good-organization-for-a-book-app-with-scraped-data

Comment: I'm missing something here.  What are you asking exactly?

Comment: What you are suggesting is _simply not done._ It is the computer equivalent of wearing white after Labor Day. Just kidding. It sounds reasonable enough to me.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to solve from the way you've worded your question.  You might get a more meaningful response if you added some details about the problem you are trying to solve and the trouble you are having with your current solution.

Comment: @joshim5: The edit really doesn't help much at all.  An explanation would be better than a link to another not-very-clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, your question is vague, but what you're proposing is a perfectly reasonable way of solving your problem as I understand it. I think what you're actually asking is what the *best* way of storing and loading your data is.

There's nothing wrong with using JSON per se, but it may not be particularly well-suited to what you wish to accomplish.  It sounds like you're dealing with documents, and XML is generally preferred for documents.  JSON is designed to be a "lightweight data-interchange format," whereas XML is designed specifically specifically for encoding documents.  XML will make your life much easier if you need to store and parse formatting information, for instance.

There are [a number of XML parsers available](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project) for iOS, and I assume there are plenty of options for JSON parsing as well.

To be honest, I'm a little confused as to why you can't simply display the original HTML documents.  If you update your question with more information about the specifics of what you're trying to do, I may be able to provide better information.